# Search Shared Drive For Files To Rename Based On Illegal Characters

Tags: java, io

I'm trying to create a modular program in Java that will search a shared drive and return all filenames, and then filter out and rename any files whose names contain illegal characters ( ex. /:*?”<>|’ )

I realize that almost every character is not allowed as part of a filename by Windows already, but they were all given as part of the list.The code I have so far is a bit disorganized and was a collaborative effort. I was able to successfully get a file copied from one directory to another, but the resulting file was blank. How can I properly get the file and all the data contained within it copied to a new directory, with all instances of the offending characters removed from the filename?

I apologize if any part of this question represents a duplication among the FAQ.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.Scanner;

import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.*;

public class FileIO {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String location = "C:\\Users\\000000000\\Desktop\\TestFiles";
        File[] files = new File(location).listFiles();
        new File(location + "/Altered/").mkdir();
        String fileName;
        for (File file : files) {
            file.toString();
            fileName = file.toString();
            String[] array = fileName.split("\\\\");
            fileName = array[array.length - 1];
            fileName = fileName.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
            fileName = fileName.replaceAll("/", "");
            fileName = fileName.replaceAll(":", "");
            fileName = fileName.replaceAll("\\*", "");
            fileName = fileName.replaceAll("\\?", "");
            fileName = fileName.replaceAll("\"", "");
            fileName = fileName.replaceAll("<", "");
            fileName = fileName.replaceAll(">", "");
            fileName = fileName.replaceAll("|", "");
            fileName = fileName.replaceAll("'", "");

            System.out.println(fileName);

            File outfile = new File(location + "/altered/" + fileName);
            if (!outfile.exists()) {
                try {
                    outfile.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new FileWriter(outfile, true)));
            Scanner inFile = new Scanner(file);
            while (inFile.hasNext()) {
                String line = inFile.nextLine();
                System.out.println(line);
                if (line != null) {

                    outFile.println(line);
                }
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: @user1886323 I've added more specifics. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks kind of OK to me - you should explain why it doesn't work in your question.

You will find this kind of task much easier by using the Java 8 methods Files.walk() and Files.walkFileTree() (the latter may be available in earlier java versions), rather than your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues:

- If a file has a name with illegal characters, it shouldn't exist in the first place. In Windows the illegal characters are /<>:*?"| (there are 9 of them). The simple quote however is valid.
- Good luck trying to create those files. Do they already exist? How do you expect to create them?
- It seems as you are already replying to your question. What specific difficulties are you having?
- As I read in the code, you are copying line by line from the source file into the target file. If you are renaming as stated in the title, you should use the `File#renameTo(File)` method. If you mean to copy the file, you should do by blocks, not lines. There is some new `Files#copy(Path,Path,CopyOption...)` in Java 8 NIO. (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html)